# Combine object and delete a property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Supposed I have an array of objects structured like this

```
"err": [
    {
        "chk" : true,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "chk" :true
        "post": "test"
    }
]
```

How can I re-structure it like this:

```
"err": [
    {
        "post": "test"
        "name": "test"
    }
]
```

I tried

```
arr.filter(obj => delete obj.chk);
```

It can successfully delete the `chk` property, but how can I combine the two objects?

Comment: which two object? after delete(which has only single object) or before delete?

Comment: What is the logic? What is the purpose of `chk`?

Comment: Do you really need the final result to be an array if there's just one object in it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can spread them into `Object.assign` to create a new object, then remove the `chk` property from that object:

```js
const err = [
    {
        "chk" : true,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "chk" :true,
        "post": "test"
    }
];
const newObj = Object.assign({}, ...err);
delete newObj.chk;
console.log([newObj]);
```

Another method, without deleting, would be to destructure `chk` on the left-hand side, and use rest syntax:

```js
const err = [
    {
        "chk" : true,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "chk" :true,
        "post": "test"
    }
];
const { chk: _, ...newObj } = Object.assign({}, ...err);
console.log([newObj]);
```

Comment: Wow! What is this `_`? :)

Comment: Just an unused variable name. Could have left it in `chk`, but that might be a bit misleading since there's no intention to use it again